# AWS RDS showing more disk usage than PgAdmin statistics

Tags: postgresql, amazon-rds

I am using AWS RDS to host one PostgreSQL database. I notice that the disk usage at the AWS dashboard is much more (2x) than what is shown at PgAdmin. Hopefully someone can help me to figure out it.

**AWS**

[image]

**PgAdmin**

[image]

I find this issue after I tried several times to create a materialized view for caching very complex query results. All failed because of out of space (for computing?). I expect the remaining space (~7GB originally) would return but it didn't!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems to be a lot of junk produced by the failed operations. A vacuum fix this issue.